# How to merge 2 arrays in php and getting no duplicate value

Tags: php, arrays

I got 2 tables like these:

```
$array1 = (2, 7, 9, 15);
$array2 = (3, 7, 10, 15);
```

I would like to get some kind of a mix of the 2 tables. Result has to be like:

```
$result = (2, 7, 9, 15, 3, 10);
```

Without any duplicate values.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
$result = array_unique(array_merge($arra1, $array2));
```

see also the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 1):

```
//First merge the two arrays
$c = array_merge($array1,$array2);

//Then use the following function to return unique values only
$unique = array_unique($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the second array and check if each value exists in the first:

```
foreach($array2 as $v) {
    if(!in_array($v, $array1)) {
        $array1[] = $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
$array1 = array(2, 7, 9, 15);
$array2 = array(3, 7, 10, 15);

$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$array3 = array_unique($array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically like this:

```
 <pre>
 <?php 
$array1 = array(2,7,9,15);
$array2 = array(3,7,10,15);
function array_merge_func($array1,$array2)
{
    foreach($array1 as $v)
    {
        if(!in_array($v,$array2))
        {
            array_push($array2,$v);
        }
    }
    return $array2;
}

$array3 = array_merge_func($array1,$array2);
print_r($array3);
?>
</pre>
```

Check if values from array1 doesnt exists in array2. If not exist push the value inside the array2.